# How to remove everything related to GIMP? (Ubuntu 19.04)

Tags: uninstall, gimp

I had spent hours just trying to add the gimp resynthesizer and it had me installing and uninstalling tons of gimps and flatpaks and a bunch of stuff I had to remove at the end because non worked. The flatpak install failed when it was at 80% and now I don't know if the stuff that didn't finish installing is still on my system. When I install GIMP from the gnome software center, I can't even resize it on my screen, I already tried many things like setting the window thing to default but it still doesn't fix it. I thought I uninstalled the entire gimp stuff but when I search "gimp" on the file manager, tons of stuff load up.

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 19.04, is there any way to remove everything from GIMP?
If you could help me a way to actually install resynthesizer on gimp 10.10 and gimp itself without any problems i'd appreciate it too. Everything I search on AskUbuntu doesn't work or it's too complicated and it's outdated, created 4-6 years ago. I am really struggling with this.

I already **sudo apt-get purge --autoremove gimp** and ppa-purged the gimp thing.

snap list:
[image]

Comment: What is the output of `snap list`? Because this files look like snap packages.

Comment: Can you add the output from the snap list to the question?

Comment: I don't know if there is an easily installed resynthesizer for Gimp 2.10, but AFAIk you can find easily installed GMIC packages, and GMIC contains a completely equivalent function (some even say it is  even a bit better).

Comment: Also, see https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Gimp-2-10-Resynthesizer-Linux

Answer (score 0):

Gimp keeps most of its user configuration in a specific directory, called the "Gimp profile". This directory is not removed when you uninstall/reinstall, so the newly installed version often inherits the problems of the previous one.

Some hints to find your Gimp profile [here](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/). These hints are for 2.8, the location has changed a bit in 2.10, but the methods to find it are still the same, if you have a working Gimp.

Otherwise you can use find to search a for a file called `gimprc`:

```
 find ~ -name 'gimprc'
```

And erase the directory that contains it and all its subdirectories. Gimp will recreate one when it starts again.